# How can I change HTML tag color like h1, h2, p etc but keeping some h1, h2 tag unchanged?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, colors

I've created a javascript file which can change colors of all the HTML tag which

I add into javascript file.
Such as If I add h1 tag into javascript file it changes all the h1 tag's color.

But I want keep some h1 tag unchanged. Is it possible to do so?
I've image caption which has black gradient background, that is why if I change all the h1 tag's color, the caption text color become unreadable. How can I solve this issue?

My Javascript file

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.blackButton').click(switchBalck);
   $('.indigoButton').click(switchIndigo);
   $('.greyButton').click(switchGrey);
   $('.redButton').click(switchRed);
   $('.bluegreyButton').click(switchBluegrey);
   $('.tealButton').click(switchTeal);
   $('.amberButton').click(switchAmber);
   $('.orangeButton').click(switchOrange);
 function switchBalck() {
   $('h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, a').attr('class', 'black');
 }
 function switchIndigo() {
   $('h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, a').attr('class', 'indigo');
 }
 function switchGrey() {
   $('h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, a').attr('class', 'grey');
 }
 function switchRed() {
   $('h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, a').attr('class', 'red');
 }
 function switchBluegrey() {
   $('h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, a').attr('class', 'bluegrey');
 }
 function switchTeal() {
   $('h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, a').attr('class', 'teal');
 }
 function switchAmber() {
   $('h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, a').attr('class', 'amber');
 }
 function switchOrange() {
   $('h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, a').attr('class', 'orange');
 }
 })
```

```css
h1.black, h2.black, h3.black, h4.black, h5.black, h6.black, a.black {
  color:#000000;
}
h1.indigo, h2.indigo, h3.indigo, h4.indigo, h5.indigo, h6.indigo, a.indigo {
  color:#3F51B5;
}
h1.grey, h2.grey, h3.grey, h4.grey, h5.grey, h6.grey, a.grey{
  color:#9E9E9E;
}
h1.red, h2.red, h3.red, h4.red, h5.red, h6.red, a.red{
  color:#E57373;
}
h1.bluegrey, h2.bluegrey, h3.bluegrey, h4.bluegrey, h5.bluegrey, h6.bluegrey, a.bluegrey{
  color:#607D8B;
}
h1.teal, h2.teal, h3.teal, h4.teal, h5.teal, h6.teal, a.teal{
  color:#009368;
}
h1.amber, h2.amber, h3.amber, h4.amber, h5.amber, h6.amber, a.amber{
  color:#FFC107;
}
h1.orange, h2.orange, h3.orange, h4.orange, h5.orange, h6.orange, a.orange{
  color:#FF9800;
}
.switcher {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.switcher li {
  float: left;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 0 15px 15px 0;
  border-radius: 30px;
  border: 3px solid black;
}

.blackButton {
  background: #000000;
}
.indigoButton {
  background: #3F51B5;
}
.greyButton {
  background: #9E9E9E;
}
.redButton {
  background: #E57373;
}
.bluegreyButton {
  background: #607D8B;
}
.tealButton {
  background: #009368;
}
.amberButton {
  background: #FFC107;
}
.orangeButton {
  background: #FF9800;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="switcher">
  <li class="blackButton"></li>
  <li class="indigoButton"></li>
  <li class="greyButton"></li>
  <li class="redButton"></li>
  <li class="bluegreyButton"></li>
  <li class="tealButton"></li>
  <li class="amberButton"></li>
  <li class="orangeButton"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: give the tags you want to change a other class or id than the tags you don't want to change

Comment: Use CSS class if you want to make changes for multiple tags or else if you want to change specific use CSS id

Comment: You could reduce a lot of code by looping over an array and applying classes in a function, at the moment you're repeating yourself quite a lot which is generally best avoided

Comment: I want to change most of the tags except some of the tags. So if I have to add additional class that will be very difficult. I've to add class into all the heading tags, link tags. Is there any other way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.) Create a CSS rule for a class that resets the color:

```
.colorreset {
  color: inherit;
}
```

2.) Use this class on the tags which you don't want to be affected, they will inherit the standard color (usually black, or what ever you define in CSS rules for `html` and `body`).

3.) Use that class it in the following way in your jQuery to exclude elements which have it from being affected by your script:

```
function switchOrange() {
      $('h1:not(.resetcolor), h2:not(.resetcolor), h3:not(.resetcolor), h4:not(.resetcolor), h5:not(.resetcolor), a:not(.resetcolor)').attr('class', 'orange');
    }
```

(same for the other functions / colors)

This excludes all tags which have class `.resetcolor` from being selected by this function.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.blackButton').click(switchBalck);
   $('.indigoButton').click(switchIndigo);
   $('.greyButton').click(switchGrey);
   $('.redButton').click(switchRed);
   $('.bluegreyButton').click(switchBluegrey);
   $('.tealButton').click(switchTeal);
   $('.amberButton').click(switchAmber);
   $('.orangeButton').click(switchOrange);
 function switchBalck() {
   $('h1:not(.resetcolor), h2:not(.resetcolor), h3:not(.resetcolor), h4:not(.resetcolor), h5:not(.resetcolor), a:not(.resetcolor)').attr('class', 'black');
 }
 function switchIndigo() {
   $('h1:not(.resetcolor), h2:not(.resetcolor), h3:not(.resetcolor), h4:not(.resetcolor), h5:not(.resetcolor), a:not(.resetcolor)').attr('class', 'indigo');
 }
 function switchGrey() {
   $('h1:not(.resetcolor), h2:not(.resetcolor), h3:not(.resetcolor), h4:not(.resetcolor), h5:not(.resetcolor), a:not(.resetcolor)').attr('class', 'grey');
 }
 function switchRed() {
   $('h1:not(.resetcolor), h2:not(.resetcolor), h3:not(.resetcolor), h4:not(.resetcolor), h5:not(.resetcolor), a:not(.resetcolor)').attr('class', 'red');
 }
 function switchBluegrey() {
   $('h1:not(.resetcolor), h2:not(.resetcolor), h3:not(.resetcolor), h4:not(.resetcolor), h5:not(.resetcolor), a:not(.resetcolor)').attr('class', 'bluegrey');
 }
 function switchTeal() {
   $('h1:not(.resetcolor), h2:not(.resetcolor), h3:not(.resetcolor), h4:not(.resetcolor), h5:not(.resetcolor), a:not(.resetcolor)').attr('class', 'teal');
 }
 function switchAmber() {
   $('h1:not(.resetcolor), h2:not(.resetcolor), h3:not(.resetcolor), h4:not(.resetcolor), h5:not(.resetcolor), a:not(.resetcolor)').attr('class', 'amber');
 }
 function switchOrange() {
   $('h1:not(.resetcolor), h2:not(.resetcolor), h3:not(.resetcolor), h4:not(.resetcolor), h5:not(.resetcolor), a:not(.resetcolor)').attr('class', 'orange');
 }
 })
```

```css
h1.black, h2.black, h3.black, h4.black, h5.black, h6.black, a.black {
  color:#000000;
}
h1.indigo, h2.indigo, h3.indigo, h4.indigo, h5.indigo, h6.indigo, a.indigo {
  color:#3F51B5;
}
h1.grey, h2.grey, h3.grey, h4.grey, h5.grey, h6.grey, a.grey{
  color:#9E9E9E;
}
h1.red, h2.red, h3.red, h4.red, h5.red, h6.red, a.red{
  color:#E57373;
}
h1.bluegrey, h2.bluegrey, h3.bluegrey, h4.bluegrey, h5.bluegrey, h6.bluegrey, a.bluegrey{
  color:#607D8B;
}
h1.teal, h2.teal, h3.teal, h4.teal, h5.teal, h6.teal, a.teal{
  color:#009368;
}
h1.amber, h2.amber, h3.amber, h4.amber, h5.amber, h6.amber, a.amber{
  color:#FFC107;
}
h1.orange, h2.orange, h3.orange, h4.orange, h5.orange, h6.orange, a.orange{
  color:#FF9800;
}
.switcher {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.switcher li {
  float: left;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 0 15px 15px 0;
  border-radius: 30px;
  border: 3px solid black;
}

.blackButton {
  background: #000000;
}
.indigoButton {
  background: #3F51B5;
}
.greyButton {
  background: #9E9E9E;
}
.redButton {
  background: #E57373;
}
.bluegreyButton {
  background: #607D8B;
}
.tealButton {
  background: #009368;
}
.amberButton {
  background: #FFC107;
}
.orangeButton {
  background: #FF9800;
}
.resetcolor {
  background: inherit !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="switcher">
  <li class="blackButton"></li>
  <li class="indigoButton"></li>
  <li class="greyButton"></li>
  <li class="redButton"></li>
  <li class="bluegreyButton"></li>
  <li class="tealButton"></li>
  <li class="amberButton"></li>
  <li class="orangeButton"></li>
</ul>
<h1>Test (click a button above to change bg color)</h1>
<h1 class="resetcolor">Test no color</h1>
<h2>Test H2</h2>
<h2 class="resetcolor">Test H2 no color</h2>
```

Comment: I'm using attr method in javascript, so whatever I give class it will replace. It is not working.

Comment: Please note my changed/extended answer

Comment: Hi Johannes. can you please check your code. If I select black and then select another color, it changes every heading. Moreover I want to make difference in same color, such as if I select black color, most of the tag will change to black except my image caption area which has gradient background. If I inherit the text color it become messy.

Comment: Hi Johannes. can you please check your code. If I select black and then select amber color, it changes every heading. Moreover I want to make difference in same color, such as if I select black color, most of the tag will change to black except my image caption area which has gradient background. If I inherit the text color it become messy.

Comment: Yes, that's because I had only applied those `:not` clauses to the last three functions for testing, as I wrote - of course it has to be applied to all of them, I did that now, and it works as expected.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Johannes. You save my day. It worked perfectly. Thanks a lot man.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to add an ordinary class name ('notAffected') to that h1 tag (which you dont want to get affected) and use jquery selector like this: $('h1:not(.notAffected), h2, h3, h4, h5, a').attr('class','whatever');

Comment: i want to make difference in the same tag not like change in h1 and h2. I want make two different changes in same tag like h1.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new class for the all the elements you want to change the color for and call the javascript on that class.

Your code will look something like this for H1, H3. You can do the same for other elements

HTML

```
<h1 class="changeColor"> This H1 will change color </h1>
<h1> This H1 won't change color </h1>
<h3 class="changeColor"> This H3 will change color </h3>
<h3> This H3 won't change color </h3>
```

CSS

```
.amber{
  color:#FFC107;
 }

.changeColor{

  }
```

Javascript

```
function switchAmber() {
  $('.changeColor').addClass("amber");
}

$( document ).ready(function() {
  switchAmber();
 });
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pa4cofeq/

Comment: If I have to add class in the tag, I've to add it in all the tags that I have in my website. Is there any way that I can control only the tags do not want to affect?

Comment: Can you give them IDs? Run the jQuery on the IDs of the elements you want the color change on